# How can I style the background-pressed of some items in a PreferenceScreen

Tags: android

I can style the background for all `Preference` items to whatever I please. How can I style a few `Pereference` items as one style (e.g. set a `listSelector`) and style the rest of the `Preference` items with a different style?

I set the style of the `Preference` to a style that sets its layout:

```
<style name="Preference.Custom">
    <item name="android:layout">@layout/preference_custom</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

In the `preference_custom.xml`, I set the background again:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/spacing_large"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@color/transparent">     <--- Here's where I set the background

...
```

All the custom styles get set except the background for the pressed state.

I've also tried setting the background to a drawable that has the pressed state set to transparent.

In my custom class of the Preference, I set the background, and I saw it change from the top entry to the bottom entry following:

```
android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable@41e30248
android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable@41de71d8
```

Here's my subclass of `Preference`:

```
public class PreferenceNoBackground extends Preference {
    private Context mContext;


    public PreferenceNoBackground(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
    }

    public PreferenceNoBackground(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
    }

    public PreferenceNoBackground(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindView(View view) {
        super.onBindView(view);
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.item_background_transparent);
    }
}
```

`item_background_transparent.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:drawable="@color/transparent" />

    <!-- Even though these two point to the same resource, have two states so the drawable will invalidate itself when coming out of pressed state. -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false"                              android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"                                android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
    <item android:state_focused="false"                               android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"                                                             android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/transparent" />

</selector>
```

I also tried setting the background from the `PreferenceFragment`:

```
    pref = findPreference(Settings.CUSTOM);
    pref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
    pref.getView(null, null).setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(
      R.drawable.item_background_transparent));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before by using 2 different layouts for the 2 different list items. In my case I showed a bunch of images then had on final item that was a website link. The relevant code in my adapter looked like this:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = null;

        if (position >= imgIds.size())
        {
            // Can we use the convertView? Only if it was expanded from R.layout.help_list_item_last...
            if (convertView != null && isLastView(convertView))
            {
                view = convertView;
            }

            if (view == null)
            { 
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.help_list_item_last, parent, false);
                if (view == null)
                    return null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ImageView helpImage = null;

            // Can we use the convertView? Only if it was expanded from R.layout.help_list_item...
            if (convertView != null && !isLastView(convertView))
            {
                view = convertView;
            }

            if (view == null)
            { 
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.help_list_item, parent, false);
                if (view == null)
                    return null;
            }
        }           
        return view; 
    }

    private boolean isLastView(View view)
    {
        if (view != null && view.findViewById(R.id.help_list_item_last) != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

To be more flexible the code could move away from using xml layouts and style each list dynamically in the getView() code. In my case it was simple to use 2 different layouts.